# Check if list entry exists in other list

Tags: python, string, list

I want to check if a list entry from one list exists in another list of strings. After this I want to delete the match from the string. See an example here:

```
list1 = ["MyFirm Geographical Enablement Framework", "MyFirm Multiresource Scheduling",
         "MyFirm SuccessFactors Recruiting"]
list2 = ["Install MyFirm SuccessFactors Recruiting in the right way",
         "Get MyFirm Geographical Enablement Framework to work"]
```

Out of this I want to create a new list with all words from list 2, except the words which are also in list 1. So see here an example output:

```
new_list = ["Install in the right way", "Get to work"]
```

My first approach would be like this, but it doesn't work:

```
new_list = []

for element in list1:
    if element.split() in list2:
        result = list2.remove(element)
        new_list.append(result)
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Why wouldn't the "work" from framework in list 1 entry 1 delete the "work" from list 2 entry 2?

Comment: Are you trying to match *complete phrases*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `set` of words to exclude from the concatenation of all words in list1. Then filter words of sentences in `list2` using that set:

```
excluded = set(" ".join(list1).split())
new_list = [" ".join(word for word in sentence.split() if word not in excluded)
                for sentence in list2]

print(new_list)  # -> ['Install in the right way', 'Get to work']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for each item (say `i`) of `list2` if any item (say `j`) of `list1` is inside that item (`i`). If inside, find the index where it starts, add the length to get the ending point, append to the `new_list` and then break out of inner loop.

This is what you need:

```
new_list = []
for i in list2:
    for j in list1:
        if j in i:
            new_list.append(i[:i.index(j)] + i[i.index(j) + len(j):])
            break

print(new_list)

# ['Install  in the right way', 'Get  to work']
```

Notice that extra space in between? For that you might have to strip of spaces and add one extra space while concatenating to get you desired result. For that change line6 to this :

```
new_list.append(i[:i.index(j)].rstrip() + " " + i[i.index(j) + len(j):].lstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` each string to get the list of words, and then re-join the strings in `list2` while filtering out those that are in the combined word list from `list1`:

```
>>> [' '.join(w for w in s.split() if w not in {w for s in list1 for w in s.split()}) for s in list2]
['Install in the right way', 'Get to work']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `set`s is the great option:
(*only if you are okay with the unordered results*)

```
list1 = ["MyFirm Geographical Enablement Framework", "MyFirm Multiresource Scheduling", "MyFirm SuccessFactors Recruiting"]
list2 = ["Install MyFirm SuccessFactors Recruiting in the right way", "Get MyFirm Geographical Enablement Framework to work"]

res = []

full_list1 = ' '.join(list1) # String
full_set1 = set(full_list1.split(' '))

for elem2 in list2:
    set2 = set(elem2.split(' '))
    tmp_diff = set2.difference(full_set1)

    res.append(' '.join(list(tmp_diff)))
```

`res` will be your desired result (list).

Comment: While I think using `set`s for fast membership testing is a great idea, I also think that they could be used in slightly different manner that would preserve the order of the words in `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
new_list = []
for it in list2:
    for r_st in list1:
        it = it.replace(r_st, '').strip()
    new_list.append(it.replace('  ', ' '))

print(new_list)

>>>
new_list=['Install in the right way', 'Get to work']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a lookup list from first list, and then iterate over the words in second list to eliminate any words that occur in the first list.

```py
lookup = ' '.join(list1).split()
new_list = []
for sentence in list2:
    sentence = ' '.join([word for word in sentence.split() if word not in lookup])
    new_list.append(sentence)

print(new_list) 
# ['Install in the right way', 'Get to work']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll round the answers a with a regex solution: make a pattern of the restricted phrases by concatenating them with `'|'`; substitute `''` for the restricted phrases in all the strings.

```
import re
a = ["MyFirm Geographical Enablement Framework",
     "MyFirm Multiresource Scheduling", "MyFirm SuccessFactors Recruiting"]
b = ["Install MyFirm SuccessFactors Recruiting in the right way",
     "Get MyFirm Geographical Enablement Framework to work"]

pattern = '|'.join('({})'.format(s) for s in a)
#print(pattern)
q = [re.sub(pattern,'',s) for s in b]
#print(q)
```